# How to allow editing of cells within HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table, cell

How can I make the blank cells editable in an HTML Table?

I would like to be able to save the text that has been entered so that the table can later be retrieved and displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`contentEditable`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable) attribute on any cell, including blank cells:

```
<td contentEditable>
```

[Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable) is very good. If using XHTML syntax, write the attribute as `contenteditable="true"`.

The attribute needs to be set separately on each cell that you wish to make editable, unless you want e.g. all cells in a table to be editable, in which case it suffices to set the attribute on the `table` attribute.

The second paragraph in the question deals with other issues and is too vague to be answered, and should be posted as separate question(s) under descriptive title(s). Generally, you can save user-entered data in a few ways, e.g. by using HTML storage (`localStorage`) via JavaScript or sending data to server-side processing with Ajax calls or via form submission.

Answer (score 0):

/**
 * This method generate html table row for insertion in html file.
 * After generating table row, this method will append
 * placeholder at the end of table row for inserting next record
 */
string generate_student_record_html(int record_num, int reg_num,
        string nic_num, string student_name, string gender, string father_name) {

```
string new_record = "";
new_record.append("<tr>");

new_record.append("<td>");
new_record.append(to_string(record_num));
new_record.append("</td>");

new_record.append("<td>");
new_record.append(to_string(reg_num));
new_record.append("</td>");

new_record.append("<td>");
new_record.append(nic_num);
new_record.append("</td>");

new_record.append("<td>");
new_record.append(student_name);
new_record.append("</td>");

new_record.append("<td>");
new_record.append(gender);
new_record.append("</td>");

new_record.append("<td>");
new_record.append(father_name);
new_record.append("</td>");

new_record.append("</tr>");
new_record.append(PLACE_HOLDER); // for next record

return new_record;
```

}